# Heatmap type plot with ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

For data of the following type, in a dataframe called df.test

```
ID    value
A1    -2
A2     0
A3     3
A4     2
```

How do I make a heatmap-type plot in ggplot2 so that I get one row with each of the values (they're discrete, but ggplot and fill require me to use them continuously) marked by a different colour or a shade?

```
ggplot(df.test, aes(x=ID, y=value)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
```

gets the colour right, but there are multiple rows corresponding to each value.

Comment: Heat maps usually have an "x" and "y" axis and a separate fill / value. does `ggplot(df.test, aes(x=ID, y=1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=value))` provide what you want?

Comment: It does solve my main problem, thank you!